# Multiple copy text button javascript

Tags: javascript

[List input text and button copy with another identify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foQYp.png)

```
        $('.btn-copytext').on('click', function(){
            // debugger;
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var copyText = document.getElementById("key_site_"+id);
            copyText.select();
            copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
            document.execCommand("copy");

            var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltiptext_"+id);
            tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
        });
```

When click button copy then window alert true value but when i'm press `Ctrl + V` then copy faild.

Comment: it may help if you post the html codes as well

Comment: `document.execCommand` is advised against: "This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."

Comment: Thank @Daniel_Knights, i had solved the problem. Inside my input html contain property disable then it not work.